# In Mule4 can In a http url how can I pass a query paramter with same key but more than one values?

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I tried something like this but it doesn't work-

```
http://training-american-ws.cloudhub.io/api/flights?destination=SFO&destination=CLE
```

Comment: Do you need to create an HTTP Request for sending a request like the one you mentioned? Please share the flow you tried.

Comment: Can you provide the context of why you want to do it this way?if you want to pass multiple values, maye be you can pass them in a comma-separated format against a single query-param.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an object to be the query params by default DataWeave implements it with a Java map that doesn't allow multiple values per key. Looks like explicitly setting the output to JSON allows it:

```
<flow name="test-http-queryParams-multivalued-key"  >
    <http:listener doc:name="Listener" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/multikey"/>
    <set-variable value='#[output application/json --- {"key1":"aaa","key1":"bbb","key1":"ccc","key2":"ddd"}]' doc:name="Set Variable" variableName="myQueryParams"/>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="values #[vars.values]"/>
    <http:request method="GET" doc:name="Request" config-ref="HTTP_Request_configuration" path="/backend" >
        <http:query-params ><![CDATA[#[vars.myQueryParams]]]></http:query-params>
    </http:request>
</flow>
```